# Loop through directory, but skip latest file

Tags: shell-script, files

I'm absolute new to bash scripting but I have to work with it.

I want to loop through a directory and upload them all to a remote server. Then I have to delete them.

Now the problem I have is following: tcpdump is writing pcap data into this dir (with rotating files), so I don't want to upload the latest file. How can I make sure that when iterating through the dir, that I'll 100-percent skip the latest one? 
Since the processes for creating the files and uploading them are running parallel, I in the moment I start the upload, there may be a "new" latest file. It wouldn't matter if I would skip uploading of the two newest files, but I don't want to upload the now-latest file.

I tried to learn bash scirpting by reading the solution for "normal" looping, but it's very confusing syntax so I'd be glad if you could help me with a starting point or point me to partial solutions which are understandable for beginners.

Thank you!

PS: The latest file has also the latest timestamp.

Comment: Is the "latest file" identified by the most recent timestamp or by a particular file name?

Comment: it has the most recent timestamp, because only tcpdump is writing the data in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the -t option of ls to sort the files by modification. In combination with the tail command you can print all files except the first one. Something like this:

```
ls -t | tail -n +2
```

In a loop it could look like this:

```
for my_file in $(ls -t | tail -n +2); do upload $my_file; rm $my_file; done
```

Comment: That looks quite promising. Is the return value a multiine string? if so, how do I loop through every line/file to process them?

Comment: I updated my Comment.

Comment: Please be _very very_ careful about processing the output of `ls`. It will break your code in horrible and unexpected ways if your file names contain characters that aresn't strict alphanumerics. Spaces for one.

Comment: @roaima thanks for your concern. I'm only using this script in a directory where I know which file names are there. But for other cases, how would you solve the problem without ls?

Comment: @wernersbacher I generally prefer `for file in *` over `for file in $(ls)`. But for this specific example, one could set the `IFS` (Internal Field Separator) to something other than space. E.g. `IFS=$'\n'` for newline.

Comment: You can also use the read command in a while loop in case of whitespaces `while read file;do echo $file; done< <(ls -t | tail -n +2)` this way setting the IFS variable is not needed.

Comment: The non-quoting of the `$my_file` expansion would furthermore use the value as a globbing pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `zsh` shell and assuming your upload command is called `upload` and takes all files as a list on its command line:

```
upload ./*(.Dom[2,-1])
```

The glob qualifier `(.Dom[2,-1]))` makes the preceding globbing pattern (`*`) match only regular files (using the `.` glob qualifier, and including hidden such files, using the `D` glob qualifier), and the expansion of the pattern would not contain the most recently modified file (`om` instructs the shell to sort the files by modification timestamp, and `[2,-1]` would pick out all but the first in the resulting list).

You could then use the same pattern to delete the transferred files, or you could use a loop:

```
for name in ./*(.Dom[2,-1]); do
    upload $name
    rm -f $name
done
```

This should handle all types of filenames, including filenames with embedded spaces, tabs or newlines.

Comment: I get syntax error, unexpected `(` in `for name in ./*(.Dom[2,-1]); do'`

Comment: @wernersbacher Probably because you aren't using `zsh` which I mentioned as a prerequisite in my first sentence.  The `bash` shell can't use these glob qualifiers.  If you're writing a script, it would be easy to make the script executable by `zsh` via the `#!`-line.

Comment: whoops, I see. Will look into it

Answer (score 0):

```
# find the latest file

latestf="$(ls -t /directory/*|head -1)";

# loop over files now

for f in /directory/* ; do 
    if [[ "${f}" == "${latestf}" ]];then
        echo "skipping file [${f}]";
    else
        echo "processing file [${f}]";
        # your upload cmd here
    fi
done
```